# How to Change PHP Variable in WordPress using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to learn ajax in a very basic way how to pass variable but I have but cannot find a very basic tutorial. What I am trying to achieve is change variable of a argument for display

page-template.php

```
$args = get_posts( array(  
  'post_type' => $posttype,
));

<input type="checkbox" id="toys">
<input type="checkbox" id="games">

  $('#toys').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $.ajax ({
          type:'POST',  
          url:    //not sure what to put here
          data:   //not sure what to put here
          success: function(data)
       {
           //how to change the post type variable?

       }

        });
       
     
    } else {
     
    }

  });
```

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_change_posttype','change_posttype'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_change_posttype','change_posttype'); 

function change_posttype() {

 $posttype ='toys';  // here is my problem of what should I put in here for ajax to process
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use, this simple template to post data using jquery, ajax and php, hope it works for you.

Note: in your html you have to put the CDN file of jquery and ajax

//in your html

```
<form id="form">
  <inpunt type="text" id="field1">
  <inpunt type="text" id="field2">

  <input type="radio" name="field3" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="field3" value="1">

</form>


<div id="publishAnswer">
    <!-- here will be the php answer -->
</div>
```

//In app.js

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {


                event.preventDefault();

                var valFieldOne = $('#field1').val();
                var valFieldTwo = $('#field2').val();
                var valFieldThree = $('input:radio[name=field3]:checked').val();

                $.post('yourFile.php', {

                    valFieldOne: valFieldOne,
                    valFieldTwo: valFieldTwo,
                    valFieldThree: valFieldThree

                },function(reponse) {
                     console.log(reponse);

                     let data = JSON.parse(reponse);

                     let result   = '';

                     data.forEach(data => {

                        result += `<p>${data.result}</p>`

                     });
                      
                      $("#publishAnswer").html(result);

                });
            });
```

//yourFile.php

```
<?php

      $submitedFieldOne = stripslashes($_POST['valFieldOne']);
      $submitedFieldTwo = stripslashes($_POST['valFieldTwo']);
      $submitedFieldThree = stripslashes($_POST['valFieldThree']);


    $json[] = array (
                 'result'=>"Ok Recieved",
                 'notes'=>"Worked",
                 );


    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;

?>
```

Comment: thanks but wordpress ajax url seems to work differently than normal ajax